# how to set static ip in android gingerbread 2.3 programmatically

Tags: android

Please help me how to set static ip in android gingerbread 2.3  Programmatically.
Means,i want to set a static IP  Programmatically for android 2.3 version(gingerbread)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) has all the flags you need

Note that Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_IP is deprecated. You might take a look at it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#WIFI_STATIC_IP)

I suggest you use [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).Also, Android 1.x and 2.x doesn't provide solution for setting static ip address.However you might use ContentResolver as:

```
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, "wifi_use_static_ip", 1); // enabling static ip
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, "wifi_use_static_ip", 0); // enabling DHCP
```